# How to Add Filter functionality in QTreeView in Python PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

[image]

I wrote this code failing to create filter functionality for QTreeView Please Help me how could i add Filter with the TreeView as seen in image below Thanks a lot for your kind help.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileSystemModel, QTreeView, QWidget, QVBoxLayout,QPushButton, QMessageBox,QDialog,QTableWidget,QTabWidget

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):


        self.treeWidget_2.setObjectName("treeWidget_2")
        #self.treeWidget_2.headerItem().setText(0, "1")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.treeWidget_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        #self.model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.Files) 
        self.model.setRootPath('')

        self.treeWidget_2.setModel(self.model)
        #m = self.treeWidget_2.selectionModel()
        #m.selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)
        self.treeWidget_2.setAnimated(True)
        #self.treeWidget_2.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.treeWidget_2.setIndentation(25)
        self.treeWidget_2.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.treeWidget_2.setWindowTitle("Dir View")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.dockWidgetContents_5)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        #------------------

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.treeWidget_2)
        self.proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self.treeWidget_2)
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.treeWidget_2.setSortingEnabled(True)

        # set model
        self.treeWidget_2.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        #self.treeWidget_2.clicked.connect(self.update_model)
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)

 #@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onTextChanged(self, text):
        self.proxyModel.setFilterRegExp(text)
```

Comment: Could you explain better, what do you want to get? For example, explain based on your code and the image that you provide what you want to obtain since the title you use is very generic.

Comment: @arif-khan also your code is missing lots of essential components. Please edit and ensure it is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (emphasis on *reproducible*).

Comment: the filter item you seeing in the image is not working it is jst a design. i just wanted to show you the design which i build and i want this design to work as i need.

Comment: Sir you are requested to please send me the example code to create this filtering functionality.

Comment: @ArifKhan What filter? nothing is indicated in the image, be detailed in your explanation for example when the word X in the QLineEdit must be shown Y in the QTreeView but now shows Z. Please use `@username`

Comment: Respected Friend. I mean to ask that , i need to filter the directories and files showing in the image , lets say if i want to search specific file from a drive or from a folder first i click on the drive or folder then i write in filter QLineEdit e.g. *.xml or a name of folder then it should search it for me and send the cursor to the specific file or folder if found. just like any search or filter option., hope i made myself clear. I saw on the web some example with proxyModel but i could not take advantage from proxyModel . eyllanesc i will be highly obliged if you help me in this regard.

Comment: @ArifKhan Edit your question and add what was stated in your last comment (obviously with better writing) in addition to providing a [MRE], please use `@username`